# Implement rate limiting for public facing API deployed in AWS

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, microservices, rate-limiting

Our public API is deployed in AWS. They are developed with different tech stacks.

We want to introduce rate limiting (based on IP, access key, etc.) for the API across many services in a generic way.

- Less or No ops effort to run
- Introducing new services and paths to existing services should not require effort on configuring API gateway

We are considering the following.

- [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) Looks easy. Not sure adding routes require effort to keep it sync with services.
- [traefik](https://github.com/containous/traefik) Looks good. But, we need to run and maintain.

What would be the suggested approach for this? Any better tools/suggestions?

Comment: API Gateway supports catch all routes with * but it "only" works with Api keys, not ips

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway with Usage Plans enabled, to enable rate limiting via API key, is going to be the recommendation for a solution on AWS. You can also look into [doing something like this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/tutorials-rate-based-blocking.html) in order to support rate-limiting by IP (although if I had to do all that for IP rate-limiting I'd probably look hard at third-party products like traefik).

As mentioned in the comments, you can configure catch-all routes in API Gateway so that you don't have to modify the configuration every time you add a new route.